# multiple environment variable in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am currently learning to use next.js in my project which is based on 'create-react-app'. I am getting trouble on setting environment variables as `.env.development`, `.env.staging` and `.env.production`.

I have tried two different way. First approach did not work at all and using second approach I can access the environment variables but it creates infinite loop. Here is the setup I tried

First Approach

```
.env.development
REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:8000

constants/urls.js
console.log("process env", process.env); // {}
export const API_ENDPOINT = process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT;

next.config.js

module.exports = withCSS({
  cssModules: true,
});

module.exports = withPlugins([[withImages]]);

package.json
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_PATH=. dotenv -e .env.development next",
    "build": "NODE_PATH=. dotenv -e .env.production next build",
    "build:staging": "dotenv -e .env.staging next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
```

Second Approach

```
.env.development
 REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:8000

constants/urls.js
console.log("process env", process.env); // {}
export const API_ENDPOINT = process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT;

next.config.js
const nextRuntimeDotenv = require("next-runtime-dotenv");
const withConfig = nextRuntimeDotenv({});

const nextConfig = {
  poweredByHeader: false,
  serverRuntimeConfig: {
    NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV,
  },
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    API_ENDPOINT: process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT || "http://localhost:3000",
  },
};

// the reason behind using multiple module.exports is that when wrapping withCss inside
// withPlugins, the css did not work. It instead gives warning that css is disabled

module.exports = withCSS({
  cssModules: true,
});

module.exports = withConfig(withPlugins([[withImages]], nextConfig));
```

This approach creates infinite loop.

Comment: Have you found solution to this?

Comment: You can use .env in new version of nextjs. Your environment variable should follow`NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix. You can then access as `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_ENDPOINT`